# Correct GCC Version for CUDA

Tags: apt, nvidia, gcc, cuda

There is version mismatch between GCC and CUDA.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/

```
$ apt policy gcc
gcc : Installed : 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1
Candidate : 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1
Version table :
*** 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 500
500 http://tr.achive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ inxi -S
No command 'inxi' found

$ apt-apt-cache policy gcc-5
gcc-5:
Installed:5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 
Candidate:5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9
Version table:
*** 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 500
500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
5.3.1-14ubuntu2 500
500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages

$ ./mnistCUDNN

cudnnGetVersion() : 7005 , CUDNN_VERSION from cudnn.h : (7005) (7.0.5)
Cuda failurer version : GCC 5.4.0
Error : unknown error
error_util.h:93
Aborting...
```

I try do run cuda. 
How will I make version correct ?

Comment: What version of CUDA did you install.  What is your Nvidia card.  Did you check it's CUDA Capability number?  CUDA 9.1 has cut off capabilities 2.1 and lower, compiles work, but runtime errors. gcc 5.4 works fine for CUDA 8 and 9.1

Comment: I installed cuda again. I think cuda wasn't properly installed.
Updated some new files...
And then I installed nvidia 390.25 driver version for linux.
Then, it is running, Test pased, test is ok.

Thank you )
I will try tensorflow next step.

./mnistCUDNN
....
Test passed !

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04
GPU GTX 1080 ti
64 bit
NVIDIA Driver 390.25 : NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.25.run
CUDA Toolkit 9.1
Python3.6.4

Answer (score 0):

Trying to reinstall CUDA with [UBUNTU Network Installation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#package-manager-ubuntu-install) has resolved this same issue. Not sure what the issue with earlier installation.